# How to key-value store with history (through timestamps) in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to store a bunch of elements inside a hash, but the key must be the timestamp at that time. How should I go about doing something like this? This is in pure Ruby not Rails.

Comment: `store ||= {}; store[Time.zone.now.to_i] = 'some info'`

Comment: `Time#zone` returns a `String` ([link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-zone)), so you can't apply `now` to it. You could do a `Time.now.to_i`, but this would only provide 1-second-granularity.  The OP needs to specify, which granularity he needs for the timestamp.

Comment: Then use `Time.now.to_f` for granularity

Comment: @Tiago since `Time.now` returns an integer, calling `to_f` is pointless.

Comment: i think instead of trying timestamp to a hash (since hash iteration is very quick, using a timestamp probably wouldn't work). Rather, organize your data into array to order it.

Comment: @maxpleaner `Time.now` does not return an integer

Answer (score 2):

That's one way to do this:

```
class Store
    def initialize()
        @hash = {}
    end

    def add(data)
        @hash[Time.now.to_f] = data
    end

    def to_s
        @hash.to_s
    end

end


new_store = Store.new

new_store.add("foo");
new_store.add("bar");

puts new_store.to_s
```

Output:

```
{1475565786.995899=>"foo", 1475565786.995907=>"bar"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = (Class.new(Hash) do
  def << value
    tap { |this| this[Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")] = value }
  end
end).new
hash << :foo
sleep 1
hash << :bar << :baz
hash
#⇒ {
#    "2016-10-04 09:44:08.816475" => :foo,
#    "2016-10-04 09:44:09.824107" => :bar,
#    "2016-10-04 09:44:09.824125" => :baz
# }
```

**NB**: I downvoted a question for putting no effort in, but answered it since this solution might be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: very nice solution. Just a quick question: is `self[Time.now] = value` somehow worse than `self.tap` thing?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko See `hash << :bar << :baz`: to chain `<<` calls this method is to return `self`.

Comment: absolutely, didn't think about it this way

Comment: @SergioTulentsev which one of [those](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/LSP)?